# CSS: letting divs overlap properly?

Tags: css, html, positioning

The problem can be seen at http://dev.breinwijzer.be/agenda-2012.

I have a range of divs that share the drupal- generated class `.views-row`. 
These divs need to grow vertically. Most of them do, but the recent ones that are added on top, overlap. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I’ve tried `min-height`, but that only makes the height of the div go across the page.
 Now I just left a combo of `min-height` and `height` Obviously since they're divs they're displayed as block so I no need to change anything there I think.

On another site i’ve come across someone’s solution using a combination of `clear:both` and then `overflow:auto`. This combination actually didn’t make scrollbars showing but rather the divs respecting eachothers height because of it.  But not this time, this time we’re seeing scrollbars when doing this combination.

Obviously no `position:absolute;` -  why would one?

So i’m really out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your HTML, not your CSS.

[image: Screenshot of HTML via inspect element]

Your first "views-row" is containing the rest of the rows, these should be outside of it. As you can see, the selected block and the blocks below that should not be contained with that parent, they should be siblings of that element.

To help further I'd need to see how you're outputting the HTML.

Comment: That's pretty amazing. The HTML is being output by drupal's logic that built this view. So that changes it into a Drupal question.

Comment: The HTML in the body of the Drupal node was absolutely stuffed with `divs`, which obviously freaked out whatever logic that dealt with outputting the HTML. So just replacing those divs with different HTML got everything smooth again. Without your help pulling me out of the box, I would have spent many more hours banging my head against css.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's intended, but all `.views-row` are inside the first one. http://cl.ly/image/1X1x2b170O0m

First try to validate your website and fix the html issues: especially these related to omitted end tags - open elements without close tag.